# Reversibility of equation $F=mv$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reversibility, dissipation, time-reversal-symmetry

Please read the following text.
This text is part of Leonardo Sauskind's book.
It says that the relation F = m v is reversible. Why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534959/2451

Comment: Hi Mkrueger. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.